# How to set up python package/module directory and class definition for intuitive naming

Tags: python, namespaces, directory-structure

I've been searching for this for ages and can't find anything. I'm an experienced programmer, but recently switched to Python.

In short, I want to expand/evolve an object-oriented library of related classes into a namespace with multiple separate files (due to complexity and the desire for increased modularity) :

Currently, I might have :

```
# file lib/NameSpace.py

class Foo(object):
     def __init__(self):
         ....

class Bar(object):
     def __init__(self):
         ....

class Baz(object):
     def __init__(self):
         ....
```

And with this my program can do this:

```
import NameSpace
a = NameSpace.Foo()
b = NameSpace.Bar()
```

Now, these classes are getting complicated and Foo and Bar are functionally different though related in the conceptual NameSpace, so I want to move them to separate files within the namespace but otherwise keep my code library the same.

So, I think I want a file structure like this:

```
lib/NameSpace
lib/NameSpace/__init__.py
lib/NameSpace/Foo.py
lib/NameSpace/Bar.py
lib/NameSpace/Baz.py
```

But this would require me to change all the runtime code to initialize these as so:

```
import NameSpace.Foo
a = NameSpace.Foo.Foo() 

# ***Boo.****   Why u not like 'a = NameSpace.Foo()'?
```

So, how I do structure these things to not have to add the 'Foo' class name to the module 'Foo'? I *could* accomplish this by editing **init**.py to be a factory, like so:

```
#lib/NameSpace/__init__.py

import NameSpace.Foo as NSF

def Foo(*args, **kwargs):
    return(NSF.Foo(*args,**kwargs))
```

But that just seems more inelegant than I expect from Python. Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `__init__.py`

```
from .Foo import Foo
from .Bar import Bar
from .Baz import Baz
```

naming the files differently than your classes prevents the overwrite.

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity, you could import the `Foo` class from the module just like this:

```
from NameSpace.Foo import Foo
```

After that, you can create an object of `Foo` class like this:

```
a = Foo()
```

If you like, you can provide a different name when you import things too:

```
from NameSpace.Foo import Foo as F
a = F()
```